# MVC WPF DataContext for two UserControls

Tags: wpf, model-view-controller, data-binding, user-controls, datacontext

I'm creating a WPF Application.

I have a View which implements two different User-Controls. 
The Data Context for each Control needs to be the same, because when I change values in one control it should effect the other one. 
As soon as I select a date in my view the DataContext (which is a List of information) should be set to each control.
I already tried Binding the List to the Control. What kinda worked. The Listbox showed that there were elements but the content was not visible.

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
    <ListView.Items>
        <Label x:Name="EmployeeId" Content="{Binding Path=EmployeeId}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <Label x:Name="ShortForm" Content="{Binding Path=ShortForm}" Width="40"/>
        <Label x:Name="Degree" Content="{Binding Path=Degree}" Width="90"/>
        <Label x:Name="WorkingHours" Content="{Binding Path=WorkingHours}" Width="30"/>
    </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

So my question is, as soon as I pass the date to my controller and he gets the needed information from the database whats the way to pass the List to my user controls. Do I need to create an Interface which is implemented by the UserControls?

I used the MVVM pattern a lot. But for this university thing we have to use mvc.
A little advice would be great.

cheers

Comment: 'The Listbox showed that there were elements but the content was not visible' - this sounds an awful lot like you didn't specify the right path for the View to display. Could you post the XAML that shows how you created the ListBox?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
    <ListView.Items>
        <Label ...
```

You've bound the ItemsSource of the ListView to a collection of Employee objects, then immediately attempted to fill it with Label objects. That's not going to work - if your ItemsSource is bound to a collection all you have to do is fill that collection in your VM/controller, *not* manually specify XAML items. The closest approximation to what I *think* you're trying to do is to use a DataTemplate to display the properties of each Employee object:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Column="0" x:Name="EmployeeId" Content="{Binding Path=EmployeeId}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ShortForm" Content="{Binding Path=ShortForm}" Width="40"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" x:Name="Degree" Content="{Binding Path=Degree}" Width="90"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="3" x:Name="WorkingHours" Content="{Binding Path=WorkingHours}" Width="30"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

For my test case I created a garbage class called Employee with property names matching yours, then created an ObservableCollection, then filled it with test values. The binding took care of the rest.

```
/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="Employees" /> property's name.
/// </summary>
public const string EmployeesPropertyName = "Employees";

private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees = null;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the Employees property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
{
    get
    {
        return _employees;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_employees == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _employees = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(EmployeesPropertyName);
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
/// </summary>
public MainViewModel()
{
    Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

    Employees.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = 1, Degree = "TestDegree1", ShortForm = "TestShortForm1", WorkingHours = 8 });
    Employees.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = 2, Degree = "TestDegree2", ShortForm = "TestShortForm2", WorkingHours = 7 });
    Employees.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = 3, Degree = "TestDegree3", ShortForm = "TestShortForm3", WorkingHours = 6 });
    Employees.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = 4, Degree = "TestDegree4", ShortForm = "TestShortForm4", WorkingHours = 5 });
    Employees.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = 5, Degree = "TestDegree5", ShortForm = "TestShortForm5", WorkingHours = 4 });
}
```

Comment: thanks! No exception or error thrown.. still not working... I left out the IDataService.. could that be the issue?

Comment: Nah, the IDataService is a leftover from the default project template. I'll delete it from the answer.

Comment: Have you checked the output pane during debug for binding errors?

Comment: ok problem solved. I integrated the code of the user control into the actual view. dependency property was missing.